# Can you please identify this Chinese movie featuring Cinderella?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I just encountered a nice Chinese movie scene on YouTube:

Although the title says Cinderella and the actress was also looking at the clock as if something would happen at 12. But, I couldn’t attach it with the original Cinderella story as the actress had the superpower to freeze time.

Can you please identify this movie? I am interested in the story. Why didn’t Cinderella’s powers to freeze time work on the CEO? And, why did she run away from the mall’s restroom just to get back there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to comments on the Youtube video you linked to, the show is called “[My Girlfriend is an Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Girlfriend_Is_an_Alien)”. It came out in 2019 and stars Wan Peng and Bie Thassapak Hsu.

This particular scene is from Episode 3, about 25 minutes in.

Comment: While there might be a number of stories about romance-crazed aliens, I have to admit that I have never seen that idea in conjunction with "heterosexual amnesia," on rainy days or otherwise. I guess that's one way of maintaining wacky romantic hijinks for the benefit of the plot.